# How to solve Passing 2 ViewModels one at a time in ascx page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have 2 ViewModels (CreateVM, EditVM) with Create.aspx and Edit.aspx. Both share template called CreateEditForm.ascx .

Now problem is in CreateEditForm.ascx template I need to define model which will be once of the above ViewModel. Suppose CreateEditForm.ascx has CreateVM defined than I can not pass EditVM from the Edit ActionResult.

How to solve this problem so that my CreateEditForm.ascx can accept both ViewModels. Any generic style?

I hope you guys understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

There's several possible approaches you can take:

1. **If your create UI and your edit UI are very similar** (e.g. if they only differ by the presence of an ID field), you can use just one viewmodel and do some conditional logic, e.g. `if (Model.Id == null)`.
2. **If your create UI and your edit UI are very similar** *you could also* use two different viewmodels which implement a common interface and create a partial view which renders just the fields in common, e.g.

   `public class SomethingEditViewModel : ISomethingViewModel { }`

   `public class SomethingCreateViewModel : ISomethingViewModel { }`

   `public interface ISomethingViewModel
   {
     // define the common fields here
   }`
3. **If your create and your edit UI's are way different**, just use 2 separate viewmodels and therefore 2 separate views.